# Android platform build failed after some library update

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic/cordova project were working properly, I could build and run the application like a charm. Since two days ago, something happened, the build were broken. The command "**cordova build android**" fails every time, with following error messages:

```
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForArm64Debug FAILED
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForArm64Debug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback
```

This issue started to happens in all of developers PCs at same day, so i'm sure isn't a particular system configuration change.

I guess is due a library update.

My environment info are:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.12.0 (/home/gustavo/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : not installed

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.0, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/gustavo/apps/android-studio-running)
   NodeJS            : v8.9.4 (/home/gustavo/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Cordova plugin list are:

```
acidhax.cordova.chromecast 0.0.1-alpha "Cordova ChromeCast"
com.example.hello 0.7.0 "Hello"
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 2.1.0 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-name 1.3.5 "Device-Name"
cordova-plugin-fullscreen 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-fullscreen"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-sim 1.3.3 "SIM"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

I tried remove each plugin one by one, and found that when remove "acidhax.cordova.chromecast" the build finish successfully.

So i started to search issues with this plugins, and found one similar: https://github.com/adjust/cordova_sdk/issues/40, i followed suggestions there but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to AndroidX plugins versions, and the breaking changes Google made a few days ago.

You should be able to resolve it by adding these plugins:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

And then `cordova clean android` and build again.

Be sure to have Android SDK 28, and I recommend updating Cordova and ionic as well.

Comment: Glad I could help